# How to remove hyperlinks, email ids, etc from a text document using regex?

Tags: regex, string, r, character, data-cleaning

I have some text documents which contains:

- Different types of emails addresses: I mean public domain such as **gmail, yahoo**,
  etc and private emails as well such as **abc@mycompany.org**...
- Different hyperlinks such as **abc.com, http://abc.com, www.abc.org,** ...

So, I wish to know if I can write a single regex command to remove all such entries from my documents for further processing, and if yes then please share some links, documents, or anything useful. **I wish to remove any sort of email id or hyperlink from the documents using regex function**. I'll be implementing the regex code in R. Since, I'm a newbie in this area so any detailed explanation will be highly appreciated.

So, if I give input as:

> "abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained http://abc.com
>   www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in"

Then I should get output as:

> "to be retained org com comm in"

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that:

```
x <- c("abc@mycompany.org", "abc.com", "http://abc.com", "www.abc.org")
gsub("(@.+$|\\..{1,3}$|(^http://)?(w{3}\\.)?)", "", x, perl=T)
```

If I better understand your question and if it is the first email adress that you need to remove:

```
 gsub("(^\\b\\S+\\@\\S+\\..{1,3}(\\s)?\\b)", "", x, perl=T)
```

otherwise:

```
gsub("(\\b\\S+\\@\\S+\\..{1,3}(\\s)?\\b)", "", x, perl=T)
```

HTH

Comment: @droopy: It looks good... But actually, I don't wish to retain any part of the email could you try with this:  
`x <- ("abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained http://abc.com www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in")`

Comment: you want to remove eamil addresses from your vector x?

Comment: Ya... my document will look something like _"abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained http://abc.com www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in"_

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this truly regex and it's likely slower but...

```
x <- c("abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained abc.com www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in")

y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+"))
paste(y[!grepl("@|\\.com|\\.org|www\\.|\\.org|\\.in", y)], collapse=" ")

## [1] "to be retained org com comm in"
```

EDIT:  For a multi-row vector wrap it up as a function and `lapply` it...

```
x <- c("abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained abc.com www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in", 
    "abc@mycompany.org aasd234bc.com to be retained abc.com www.abc.org org com .com comm in sahgo234@flkja23.in")

FUN <- function(x) {
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+"))
    paste(y[!grepl("@|\\.com|\\.org|www\\.|\\.org|\\.in", y)], collapse=" ")
}
unlist(lapply(x, FUN))

## > unlist(lapply(x, FUN))
## [1] "to be retained org com comm in" "to be retained org com comm in"
```